# Selecting Email Account from google_sign_in during Flutter integration testing

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, google-signin, flutter-test

I was trying to test sign-in to my home screen for my flutter app. I am using the google-signin ( https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package from Flutter to perform login and authentication. So once the login button is pressed, a popup appears asking the user to select the user account. At that point, I am unable to control the tap as this dialog screen is generated by the plugin. How do I implement selection of the user account in this case ?

```
    test('Test Login', () async {
  final Timeline timeline = await driver.traceAction(() async {
    await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('GoogleLogin'));
    await driver.tap(find.text('myemail@gmail.com')); // This will not work !!!
  });

  TimelineSummary.summarize(timeline)
    ..writeSummaryToFile('home_scroll_perf', pretty: true)
    ..writeTimelineToFile('home_scroll_perf', pretty: true);
});
```

In my opinion, this could be a problem when testing with any third party plugin. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by selecting email address? When you login with Google you just get back if the login was successful. I think you can query the email afterwards.

Comment: Not always. You are logged in straight away only if you are already logged in/authenticated. Otherwise, a popup with the list of gmail addresses present in the phone will be listed so that the use can select the right one.  
Also, when we run flutter driver, it start the app afresh. Hence you will be prompted to signin again.

Comment: Yes but what do you want to control there?

Comment: I am writing integration test. So for that I would want the flutter driver to test sign in, select the appropriate login and continue as a human user would. I can only control what the driver would do in my app, the code and widgets I have written. So how will I go over the popup invoked by the plugin ?

Comment: Good question. I fear you won't be able to do so because to make the login save its designed that only user interacts with the auth dialog.

Comment: Interacting with social media using flutter driver is not possible as of today. This is github issue for more info: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34345

Comment: @Darshan, update after 3 years: still not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is still existing. There is no available workaround yet. Keep an eye on [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34345) as this is closely monitored by the Flutter team.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Patrol](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol), it lets you very easily interact with native UIs such as the Google sign-in dialog.

Below is a rough example of how I'd approach this. I'm going to assume that you're already signed in to a Google account, so the only thing you have to do is to select an email from the dialog.

```dart
// integration_test/sign_in_test.dart

void main() {
  patrolTest(
    'signs in with Google',
    nativeAutomation: true,
    (PatrolTester $) async {
      await $.pumpWidgeAndSettle(YourAppWidget());

      await $('Sign in with Google').tap();
      await $.native.tap(Selector(text: 'your.email@gmail.com'));
      await $.pumpAndSettle();

      // should be signed in now
    },
  );
}
```

Remember: that integration tests has to be run with `patrol drive`, not `flutter test integration_test`.